# Jquery .show and oninput- nothing happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with oninput and .show event:

```
              <!-- NAME -->
                <label>Meu nome completo é <input type="text" name="nome" class="linha_embaixo cor_input" oninput="$('label[name=email]').show('slow');" /></label> <br>

                <!-- EMAIL -->
                <label name="email" class="escondido email">e uso o email <input type="email" name="email" class="linha_embaixo cor_input" /></label><br>
```

When i start to type, label "email" is not displayed... What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1st: I added a css class to hide email label/input

```
.hideme {
 display: none;
}
```

2nd: try to not use inline script, not a good practice. (define an unique id for the name input then add an oninput event to it)

3rd: If it is not working, make sure you have jQuery?

hope this will help you!

```js
$("#inputName").on("input", function(e) {
   $('#email_label').css('display', 'inline-block');
   $('#linha_embaixo').css('display', 'inline-block');
});
```

```css
.hideme {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- NAME -->
<label>Meu nome completo é
  <input type="text" name="nome" class="linha_embaixo cor_input" id="inputName" />
</label>
<br>

<!-- EMAIL -->
<label name="email" class="escondido email hideme" id="email_label">e uso o email
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email_input" class="linha_embaixo cor_input" />
</label>
<br>
```

Comment: Hi. My code works fine, except $('label[name=email]').show('slow'). I put it in chrome console and not works

Comment: @PedroAntônio if you put a console.log(' TEST '); inside $("#inputName").on("input", function(e) { ... } are you able to trigger the console.log???

Comment: @PedroAntônio check the updated code, I added `id="email_label"` to email label (the container), and `id="email_input"` to input, for js using `css('display', 'inline-block');` instead of show. see if it is working

Comment: thanks.... My problem was in a simple !important in the css that hid the content... Thanks for help :)

Comment: @PedroAntônio try to not use too much !important in css unless you 100% sure what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The class "escondido" was hiding my content, to show with .show.

```
.escondido{
    display: none!important;
}
```

I just remove the `!important`

```
.escondido{
    display: none;
}
```

Now, `$('label[name=email]').show('slow');` works fine :)

Thanks